# Azure DevOps IIS Deployment deploy to different machine (web server) than Agent is running on

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

we would like to set up Azure DevOps deployment pipelines in a way there is one single server with Azure DevOps Agent running in the network and this server is used to deploy IIS websites/applications to multiple different servers (without Azure DevOps agent installed) on the same local network as is server with Azure DevOps Agent running.

The thought is,
the Agent running on machine in local network will be contacted from cloud to perform operation, it will download the sources from repository, do build up and then connect to different server(s) (based on given deployment pipeline setup) on local network and deploy the package there.

I suppose, we should create Deployment group job and select group containing server running the Agent and somewhere else specify the final target machines (different than agent) to which web site should be published.

Probably I have wrongly asked google, but I was unable to find answer if this is possible and how to set it up -  is there any workaround how this could be achieved or any practical example with this setup which could be shared ?

Trying to set up IIS Deploy Website/App task for this, but I was unable to find any direct setting how to achieve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to separate your build and release processes. You can use Azure Pipelines (Pipelines tab on the left side of the screen, Pipelines sub-option) (I'd likely recommend YAML, since it's the more supported and reusable way to do builds) to do most of the building (on a machine in an [agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser) of machines), and then build a completely separate [Classic Release Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) using a completely separate deployment pool.